# Parse ASP.NET C# Dictionary data into Google visualization chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, charts

I have a ASP.net application with C# as the server-language.
I here have a dictionary with data, that i want to put inside a google visualization chart. I have to create the chart dynamically at runtime, so no hardcoded HTML markup. I have a document that i want to print to the website, but fill in my own data:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var data;
     var chart;

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create our data table.
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', '');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Serie1'); // DATA HERE
        data.addColumn('number', 'Serie2'); // DATA HERE
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3,4], // DATA HERE
          ['Onions', 1,4],// DATA HERE
          ['Olives', 1,6],// DATA HERE
          ['Zucchini', 1,7],
          ['Pepperoni', 2,4]// DATA HERE
        ]);


        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      function selectHandler() {
        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
        var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        alert('The user selected ' + value);
      }

    </script>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
```

So how do i format my Dictionary-data and replace the dummy-data???

Comment: Share your sample of dictionary.

Comment: Januar 2015: 3129
Februar 2015: 1859
Marts 2015: 3002
April 2015: 2473
Maj 2015: 3015
Juni 2015: 3662
Juli 2015: 2160
August 2015: 2250
September 2015: 1944
Oktober 2015: 1711
November 2015: 874
December 2015: 628
Januar 2016: 960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Razor to insert datas from your dictionary to the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
....
    data.addRows([
          @Model.DataRows
    ]);
....
</script>
```

Define your model:

```
public class ChartModel
{
    ....
    public string DataRows { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and place at the top of the view something like: `@model [Your_Namespace].ChartModel`.

Then set the `DataRows` property in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> datas = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        datas.Add("Januar 2015", 3129);
        datas.Add("Februar 2015", 3129);
        ChartModel model = new ChartModel();
        model.DataRows = string.Join(", " + Environment.NewLine, 
            datas.Select(d => "['" + d.Key + "', " + d.Value + "]"));
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Some example?

Comment: Looking good! i am a little confused though. Where is the script going to be placed? I can't hardcode it in the aspx (HTML-file) because i have to generate a unknown amount of these charts in runtime. The data formatting looks nice! thanks

Comment: @CasperTraberg-Larsen You can place your script just like you have shown it in your question - on the page. Every time your page will be generated a new version of your script will be produced. You can also call an action method from your JavaScript code, see: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/18/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript.aspx/

Comment: The thing is: The script is not on the page. I would somehow inject it into an empty div on runtime. So 'div.InnerHTML += scriptString;' for every chart that i have to generate and put on the page. But it seems like a bad solution with a huge string containing the script, being pushed to the div at runtime.

Comment: @CasperTraberg-Larsen Then this article should help: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/18/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript.aspx/